# CSS with AngularJs custom validation

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble getting a message to display when the field input is invalid. I can see the classes being correctly applied to the element i.e.  ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-pattern so I just need to make the error message display. Is there an issue with my html?

Thanks!

```
<form ng-controller="FormCtrl" name="TestForm" action="http://myserver/api" method="post" novalidate>

<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="vld" name="vld" data-ng-pattern="/(^$)|(\b\d{9}\b)/" data-ng-model="model.tfn">
  <span class="error" data-ng-show="model.tfn.$invalid">Correct input etc...</span>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: First of all data-mg-model should be data-ng-model.

Comment: Also it would help if you show us your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you are looking for is part of the FormController. You need to setup a formController via ng-form directive:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-form="myForm">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="vld" name="vld" data-ng-pattern="/(^$)|(\b\d{9}\b)/" data-mg-model="model.tfn">
  <span class="error" data-ng-show="myForm.vld.$invalid">Correct input etc...</span>
</div>
```

If this is done you may access the information by [Name of the OFrmController].[Name of the input field].$invalid e.g. myForm.vld.$invalid

Comment: Thanks @Michael - can I clarify does need a separate directive to validate or can it be done through the main FormCtrl?

Comment: @MikeW you will only need a directive, if ng-pattern (or other existing directives) did not match your needs. if the pattern is enough you don't need any controller code.